# modify class of an element inside jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want to replace the "username" in the class of current selector with the username provided by the user in jquery dialog.problem is that i cant user $(this).attr() inside of jquery dialog button coz it will refer to the jquery dialog.Please suggest how to replace word username with user input in jquery dialog.Thanks in advance

```
<form action="#" method="post" >
</form>
<p id="text" class="www.username.google.com"> click me </p>
<div id="test" class="sandy" > 
    <input id="username" class="sandy1" />
</div>
```

==============================================================================

```
$('#text').click(function(){
    var provider_url= $(this).attr('class');
    $('.sandy').dialog({
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                if($('#username').val() == '') {
                    $('#username').focus();
                } else {
                    var myvalue= $("#username").val();
                    var nextval= replace(provider_url, username,myvalue);
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    alert(nextval);
                    $('form').append(nextval);
                    $('form').submit();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the jsfiddle code demo is at here http://jsfiddle.net/zCFD5/127/.Please help me out
​

Comment: my html code is being used in php which i omitted lated for brevity but ya u can say its not related to PHP

Comment: Do you wish to replace id "username" with text provided by user , when you click on #text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#text').click(function() {
    var provider_url = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.sandy').dialog({
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                if ($('#username').val() == '') {
                    $('#username').focus();
                } else {
                    var myvalue = $("#username").val();
                    var nextval = provider_url.replace(/\.username\./, "." + myvalue + ".");
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    alert(nextval);
                    $('form').append(nextval);
                    $('form').submit();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCFD5/130/)

It's worth noting though that you should really use `data` attributes for this, rather than storing it in the `class`. You'll need to upgrade your version of jQuery to do this though.

Also, I included the leading and trailing `.` in the regex so that you're definitely replacing the right part of the url in cases like this: `http://www.username.superusername.com`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your current problem is not due to a "this" reference issue but a wrong js/jQuery code.

Instead of :

```
var nextval= replace(provider_url, username,myvalue);
```

Write :

```
var nextval= provider_url.replace('username', myvalue);
```

and it will work better.

**Edit:** As Rory said, don't use class attribute to store values. It's not a good way to do it. If you already know the final url, maybe you could hardcode it into your button callback. If your string can change, maybe pass it in a function parameter which will create your dialog.

Comment: tahnks y'all Rory McCrossan and Mordhak.i got my mistake.thanks for the help